# При удалении элемента через setState удаляется весь массив в React

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

Никак не могу понять, почему при использовании splice удаляется весь массив.
Возле каждого li есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую удаляется именно этот элемент li. Но удаляется весь массив.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {arr: ['Коля', 'Вася', 'Петя', 'Иван', 'Дима']};
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
}

deleteItem(index) {
   this.setState({arr: this.state.arr.splice(index, 1)});
}
    
render() {
    
    const list = this.state.arr.map((item, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>
            {item}
             <button onClick={this.deleteItem}>Delete me</button>
        </li>;
    });      

        
    
    return (
            <ul>
                {list}
            </ul>      
            
 
    );
}
}
```

Нашла решение, но правильно ли понимаю, что там непосредственно меняется state и так делать нельзя.

```
deleteItem(index) {
    this.state.items.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({items: this.state.items});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Это изменит исходные данные.

Вы можете использовать [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). для создания новых данных. Пример:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { arr: ['Коля', 'Вася', 'Петя', 'Иван', 'Дима'] }
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this)
  }

  deleteItem(index) {
    this.setState({ arr: this.state.arr.filter((item, i) => index !== i) })
  }

  render() {
    const { arr } = this.state

    return (
      <ul>
        {arr.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {item}, {index}
            <button onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)}>Delete me</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

И вы должны пройти `index`: `onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)}`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.